# Why it writes in a 7 rows since i want it 7 columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, export-to-csv

Read the file and select a specific rows and columns and write it in csv file. 
Why it makes in a 7 rows since i want it 7 columns

```
data = pd.read_csv(r'dataset.csv', low_memory=False, header = None, sep = ',') 
a = data.loc[478:749, 1] 
b= data.loc[478:749, 8 ]
c= data.loc[478:749, 15 ]
d= data.loc[478:749, 22 ]
e= data.loc[478:749, 29 ]
f= data.loc[478:749, 36 ]
g= data.loc[478:749, 43 ]

x= []
x.append(a)
x.append(b)
x.append(c)
x.append(d)
x.append(e)
x.append(f)
x.append(g)

data = pd.DataFrame(x)
data = data.to_csv('summary.csv', index = False, header = None, sep = ',',quotechar =';',  encoding = 'utf8')
```

This is the result when the write to summary file

[image]

Comment: Your question is already answered but here's another way of doing it which you might find useful: data_subset = data[478:749][[1,8 15, 22, 29, 36, 43]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are selecting out the columns as Series, and then appending each series to a list, thereby transposing rows and columns.

You can either update your append to be a little more complex, adding the data column-wise, or you can use the `.T` property of the DataFrame to get the transpose. That will give you your columns as you expect.

E.g. `data = pd.DataFrame(x).T`

Answer (score 0):

The answer is

```
data = pd.read_csv(r'dataset.csv', low_memory=False, header = None, sep = ',') 
a = data.loc[478:749, 1] 
b= data.loc[478:749, 8 ]
c= data.loc[478:749, 15 ]
d= data.loc[478:749, 22 ]
e= data.loc[478:749, 29 ]
f= data.loc[478:749, 36 ]
g= data.loc[478:749, 43 ]

x= []
x.append(a)
x.append(b)
x.append(c)
x.append(d)
x.append(e)
x.append(f)
x.append(g)

data = pd.DataFrame(x).T
data = data.to_csv('summary.csv', index = False, header = None, sep = ',',quotechar =';',  encoding = 'utf8')
```

And the result should be with 7 columns

[image]